# Como ver e definir valores pra uma model usando o django template

Tags: django, django-admin

O django tem arquivos HTML que podemos sobrescrever, um deles se chama `app_list.html`, o qual tem o código a seguir:

```html
{% if app_list %}
  {% for app in app_list %}
    <div class="app-{{ app.app_label }} module{% if app.app_url in request.path %} current-app{% endif %}">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section" title="{% blocktranslate with name=app.name %}Models in the {{ name }} application{% endblocktranslate %}">{{ app.name }}</a>
        </caption>
        {% for model in app.models%}
              <tr class="model-{{ model.object_name|lower }}{% if model.admin_url in request.path %} current-model{% endif %}">
```

Esse codigo itera sobre as models dos apps que temos cadastrados, se você reparar nós conseguimos recuperar alguns atributos como em `model.amin_url` na linha 9, e podemos usar condicionais nelas.

O que eu gostaria de saber é: Como conseguimos inserir esses atributos nas models? eu tentei realizar esses condicionais com campos do `models.py`e não funcionou. Tentei adicionar no `admin.py` e também não funcionou. No `admin.py`coloquei algo assim:

```
@admin.register(TipoCurso)
class TipoCursoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome', )
    is_config = True
```

eu iria utilizar esse `is_config` para fazer uma aba personalizada apenas com as models que tivesse ele setado como `True`,mas infelizmente essa solição não funciou, alguém teria uma idéia de como definir esses atributos de models para serem usadas nos templates?

Comment: inserir atributo 'object_name' por exemplo? não entendi bem... Eu já resolvi problema em template com TemplateTag. Inserir um atributo existente na apresentação do template pode ser feito diretamente no class Meta, Só precisa saber chamar a função certa. Nesse caso de apresentar em abas, suponho q é uma questão mais voltada pro Bootstrap do que pro Django, fazer algo como {% if app.name == x %} e seguir o código